# Web security concern for Mixed content

Tags: php, wordpress, https, mixed-content

I am losing the green padlock on my WordPress website due to an image loading over `http` rather than `https`.

Is this really a risk or is the browser being overly harsh?

Comment: very tough question,, Google and major players in the security field today are pushing ssl, and if there is any chance that you can switch to https than do it, if not, consider it in the near future

Comment: Why do you don't download it from the HTTP server and put it onto your https WordPress server?

Comment: I have changed that now. It was a hard link somewhere in the code and always had https as an option. But I just wondered if it was ever a risk for the client? Is it possible or common for images to be hit with malicious code? 

Sorry guys looks like I just found an answer here!! http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/55061/can-malware-be-attached-to-an-image Should I close?

I did try searching before with all variations but had no luck.

Comment: its not a security risk at all. The image is downloaded on it's own TCP connection. The clients computer can not be compromised because of this. However, if the image contains lets say a nude photo of the client; certainly it should be transferred over a secured connection. This is a matter of privacy and not security. You should use https connections wherever possible though, the green padlock makes people feel safe for whatever reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR**

> Is this really a risk or is the browser being overly harsh?

The answer to the first facet of your question above is relative and can be opinionated; being pedantic, YES, it is a risk as that which is "not secured" can be tempered with.

Security here as the essence and concern as one makes mention of risk(s) is regarded by some as a *state* rather than a *process* (... quite a debatable topic).

Answering whether your browser is overly harsh, NO, as this depends on it's settings and by default, it should act as you've just noticed.

As such, I hope the explanation below will enable you understand further.

---

You are surely serving your WordPress site resources with [**Mixed Content**](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/prevent-mixed-content/what-is-mixed-content)**s**. In other words, some of the resources on your WordPress site are served over [**`https`**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS) while others (an image, in this very case) are served over [**`http`**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol).

In your browser's console (accessible with the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd> keyboard combination when using the Google Chrome browser), you would have see an error similar to the one below when accessing the page that contains the image in question:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://example.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an
insecure script 'http://example.com/img/avatar.png'. This request has been blocked; the
content must be served over HTTPS.
```

What this simply means is that while your website (and other referenced resources) were loaded over `https`, your image file, avatar.png, was loaded over `http` and as such was regarded as *insecure* by your browswer.

To resolve this challenge, make sure to load your image (as well as all other affected resources, should there be) over `https` by searching and replacing all `http` occurrences with `https` throughout your project.

*... more details [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content/How_to_fix_website_with_mixed_content).*